# i18next best practice

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization, multilingual, i18next

I've successfully implemented i18next, which by the way is a great library! Though I'm still in search for the "best practice". This is the setup I have right now, which in general I like:

```js
var userLanguage = 'en'; // set at runtime

i18n.init({
    lng                 : userLanguage,
    shortcutFunction    : 'defaultValue',
    fallbackLng         : false,
    load                : 'unspecific',
    resGetPath          : 'locales/__lng__/__ns__.json'
});
```

In the DOM I do stuff like this:

```html
<span data-i18n="demo.myFirstExample">My first example</span>
```

And in JS I do stuff like this:

```js
return i18n.t('demo.mySecondExample', 'My second example');
```

This means I maintain the English translation within the code itself. I do however maintain other languages using separate `translation.json` files, using i18next-parser:

```js
gulp.task('i18next', function()
{
    gulp.src('app/**')
        .pipe(i18next({
            locales : ['nl','de'],
            output  : '../locales'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('locales'));
});
```

It all works great. The only problem is that when I've set `'en'` as the `userLanguage`, `i18next` insists on fetching the `/locales/en/translation.json` file, even though it doesn't contain any translations. To prevent a 404, I currently serve an empty json object `{}` in that file.

Is there a way to prevent loading the empty .json file at all?

Comment: Have you considered using a custom loader?

Comment: Or allow the 404! This is what happens when it cascades through the fallbacks anyhow. An expected 404 isn't going to break the application unless you set some sort of global handler to "halt execution on any 404 errors."

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing something here but couldn't you simply do this:

```
if (userLanguage != 'en') {

    i18n.init({
        lng                 : userLanguage,
        shortcutFunction    : 'defaultValue',
        fallbackLng         : false,
        load                : 'unspecific',
        resGetPath          : 'locales/__lng__/__ns__.json'
    });
}
```

That way your script i18n wouldn't be initialized unless you actually needed the translation service.

Comment: That'll work for the DOM labels, but in that case I don't think the i18n.t(key, defaultString) method will process properly.

Comment: @RonaldHulshof: You could also create a dummy i18n object with the t method that simply returns defaultString. `var i18n = { t: function(key, value){ return value; }}`

Answer (score 4):

`i18next-parser` author here, I will explain how I use `i18next` and hopefully it will help:

1/ I do not use `defaultTranslation` in the code. The reason is that it doesn't belong in the code. I understand the benefit of having the actual text but the code can get bloated quickly. The difficult part consists in defining intelligible translation keys. If you do that, you don't really need the defaultTranslation text anymore. The translation keys are self-explainatory.

2/ If you have a 404 on the `/locales/en/translation.json`, then probably that you don't have the file in your `public` directory or something similar. With gulp you can have multiple destination and do `dest('locales').dest('public/locales')` for instance.

3/ If there is no translation in the catalog, make sure you run the gulp task first. Regarding populating the catalog with the defaultTranslation you have, it is a tricky problem to solve with regexes. Think of this case `<div data-i18n="key">Default <div>translation</div></div>`. It needs to be able to parse the inner html and extract all the content. I just never took the time to implement it as I don't use it.

Comment: In regard of 3/ Populating the catalog: Text labels in good semantic HTML should not contain `<div>` tags, only tags like `<em>` and `<strong>`. If someone intents to use non semantic HTML, he/she is better of not to use the auto-population feature. For anyone else, it could be a great, great, great feature. Now that I have been using the text inline as described for roughly 9 months, I am still very pleased with the choice I made back then. In my development team, this way of working with translation, works very very well.

Comment: I understand, though I don't think "good semantic HTML" justifies not parsing all scenarios. If you make a PR that covers all scenarios (div in div) I will review it but at the moment I can't spend time on this library.

Answer (score 2):

See http://i18next.com/pages/doc_init.html under "whitelist languages to be allowed on init" (can't fragment link on those docs...):

```
i18n.init({ lngWhitelist: ['de-DE', 'de', 'fr'] });
```

> Only specified languages will be allowed to load.

That should solve your problem. Though I suppose a blacklist would be even better.

Comment: This actually blocks loading i18next when I define 'en' as the userLanguage. Or better said, it'll even crash i18next.

Comment: @RonaldHulshof That's weird. I can't imagine that's the intent of the whitelist option. Is one of your init options conflicting with it?

Comment: No, the above configuration is the one I actually use.